# Does a pure-python package for reading HDF5 files exist?

Tags: python, hdf5

The package [`h5py`](http://www.h5py.org/) needs `libhdf5-dev` (on Debian systems) to be installed. This is a problem as I don't have superuser rights on some systems where I need to read HDF5 files.

Is there a Python package which does not need non-Python packages to read (very simple) HDF5 files?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's no such package. But you don't need to install libhdf5 system-wide. Just install/compile it somewhere in your home directory and then tell h5py where it is:
$ HDF5_DIR=/path/to/libhdf5 pip install h5py

See the manual for details: http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so I have to write my comment here. You can install the entire python stack in your home directory. This way, you have full control of the python installation.

I am using anaconda python which comes with h5py and I installed it in my home directory. I can install any packages I want or update them  whenever I want. For example many packages have recently seen many improvements including stability improvements.

Comment: The problem isn'T that I cannot install Python packages. The problem is that I cannot install h5py without libhdf5-dev (which is not a Python package).

Comment: When you install a full stack like anaconda you do not need any libs. Its fully independent.

Comment: I think the conda package manager handles non-python dependencies pretty well (as opposed to pip). So if you do a 'conda install h5py', it also installs libhdf5. Check out http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html.

Comment: I am using anaconda python on a computer with an ancient kernel. All C/C++ compilers I have on that machine are at least 8-years old.